# jQuery jwizard plugin

Tags: jquery, jwizard

looks like `nextStep()` method inside **jquery.jwizard.js** is being called when the user clicks on next button. Is it possible to call that method explicitly and pass some options so that I won't see cancel button in next screen? how can I?

plz check the working example at: http://dominicbarnes.us/jWizard/demo/menu.html

Answer (score 1):

[Based on the examples](http://dominicbarnes.us/jWizard/demo/publicmethods.html), I'd say you can programatically jump to the next step like this:

```
$w = $("#jWizard");
$w.jWizard("nextStep");
```

In order to hide the cancel button you can [set the corresponding option](http://dominicbarnes.us/jWizard/demo/allconfig.html):

```
$("#jWizard").jWizard({
    buttons: {
        cancelHide: true
    }
});
```